# Nginx redirect if isn't wp-admin or wp-login.php

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I want my nginx to redirect everything which isn't poiting to the wp-admin folder or to wp-login.php from https:// to http:// (If is https). My vhost config just says

```
 server{
         listen 80;
         listen 443 ssl;
```

and then some things about the server name, the certi info and error pages. Can anyone tell me how to force the use of http instead of https to every folder that isn't wp-admin and every file that isn't wp-login.php ?

Comment: Why not let your visitors talk to you over HTTPS if they so choose?

Comment: Because I only have a self-signed HTTPS certificate. It is just for the login process.

Comment: [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/) offers free certificates from a widely-trusted CA. The website is a little confusing (and will try to up-sell you), but it does in fact issue usable certs.

Answer (score 2):

My current solution to this is to not rewrite urls in nginx at all, but let Wordpress itself do the job.

My nginx is configured to allow both http and https, like yours, so people can choose which they want as I use CAcert certificates which are not trusted by everyone. Then I make Wordpress forcing login and admin sessions to redirect to https by adding this to `wp-config.php`:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

This doesn't redirect https to http on non-admin pages, though. But that doesn't really make sense, as it doesn't avoid certificate warnings: The redirection will only happen after the warning. And on the other hand, some people (e.g. the admins) actually have imported the certificate and might want to use the rest of the site with https, too.

More details can be found at http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL. I stumbled over this via http://www.surlyjake.com/blog/2011/12/20/wordpress-https-secure-login-with-nginx/.

Answer (score 1):

In your server block, use location rules to match the */wp-admin/* and */wp-login.php* requests and rewrite those to use *https*, and for everything else -- if that's what you want --  rewrite to use *http*. For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name your.domain.name;

    # your ssl configurations here...
    # example:
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ http://$server_name$request_uri? last;
    }

    location /wp-admin/ {
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? last;
    }

    location = /wp-login.php {
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? last;
    }

    # your other rules here...

}
```